# Update mysql partial based on another field

Tags: mysql

I have field1 and field2.

if field2=123456789

i want to take the first 3 int and update field1 with it
so field1=123

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTable SET field1= SUBSTRING(field2,1,3)
```

Will make all field1's equal to the first 3 char's of field2. You can add a `WHERE field2 = 123456789` if needed

Answer (score 2):

update yourtable set field1 = substring(field2, 1, 3) where field2 = 123456789;

Comment: thanks for you as well, but Nanne was a second faster. but rep+