# How to update a field based on the update of another field?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I have two fields. One is customerid and the other is custidref. The custidref is the last 6 digits of the customerid field. I did a search to find a similar problem and came across this:

[Update mysql partial based on another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707833/update-mysql-partial-based-on-another-field)

While this problem is the same as mine, I have to use another method to get my substring. I'm using a dictionary written in Python. Unfortunately, I can't use a regular update query because the dictionary is based on a library code written by someone else. The code I have is this:

```
for valuedict in valuedictlist:

    fieldupdate=customertypedict['fieldupdate']
    newaccount=valuedict['newaccount']
    fieldref=customertypedict['fieldref']

    if customertypedict['table']=='customer' and customertypedict['product']=='insurance':
        customerobj.custidref=customerobj.customerid[-6:]
        customerobj.fieldref=fieldref

    customerobj.Change({'changedict':{fieldupdate:newaccount,fieldref:customerobj.custidref}})
```

I am wondering-- am I updating the custidref field properly based on the change of the customerid field? What I have happening is the custidref is one update behind. Instead of having the 6 digits of the current customerid, it has the digits from the previous customerid.

Comment: Hope mySql 'on update cascade' would help

Comment: I can only use code in python format, not mysql...if I could, this would be way easier!

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#save-update

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. I changed the code to this:

```
customerobj.Change({'changedict':{fieldupdate:newaccount,fieldref:newaccount[-6:]}})
```

This grabbed the 6 digits as necessary, and I was able to eliminate a line of code.